# i want to merge 2 databases with Talend Open Studio

Tags: database, talend, tmap

my job is to merge 2 databases, one is on sql server and the other one is a metadata !! i used tmap to make the second database having the same schema as the first one !!
the 2 databases have id in commun, i want a final database that has all the id with no redundancy !!!
please i need help as soon as possible
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRvpt.png)

i dont know if i should use tmap or something else to merge the 2 databases

Answer (score 0):

using the tMap, you can configure a join on the common ID, i you want no redundancy. You can choose the inner join join type (join model) and catch the inner join reject output like this.[image]

Then add a second output in the tMap that doesn't catch the inner join reject and use the component tUnite to combine the two data flows.

Comment: here is the documentation for the tUnite (https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/8.0/orchestration/tunite) and tMap (https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/8.0/tmap/tmap?tocId=xh4Ajmpb9XV6L2lTX0jX~Q) components